# How can I get my Steam account to show youtube videos that are added?

Tags: steam

I am having a problem in my steam account regarding adding video from a Youtube account in my steam.
Previously I have added couple of videos from a youtube account to my steam without any trouble, 
but from yesterday when I try to add a video from my steam it's showing "1 video added into your steam profile" but it's not really added and not showing in the added videos list.

Is it because of the latest steam update or the update of Youtube account connected with  Google+ and Gmail?

Comment: When I try to connect Steam to my YouTube account, I get the error "There was an error accessing YouTube to retrieve your username. Please try again." - I suspect this is because my YouTube account now has the silly aliased account thing due to Google+ integration. Not sure how you'd fix it

Comment: i didnt do anything . it was all goin smooth whn i added the previous videos six months earlier, now i found the trouble. and hell'ya its may b bcoz of that related account.

Comment: Yeah Google have made a change to the way they work, I have never linked my Google account to Steam, so when I try to now, it tries to add my main Google account using my name which doesn't actually have anything on YouTube rather than my YouTube account (which uses an alias) with no option to change between the two. I imagine that since you've already added your YouTube account in the past, the new method of authentication is messing something up - this is probably a Google problem more than a Steam problem based on the screens I saw when trying to link my accounts.

Comment: I was told to put a bounty on this question instead of making a new question. This is still unresolved as unlinking your google+ account from youtube DOES NOT WORK!

Answer (score 2):

I found out the solution though not a convincing one but it will do the job.

It may be because of the link of all the profiles from youtube to google (and its services) which is causing the trouble. To add the videos in steam, you need to create an account anonymously and then upload the same videos there.

Later granting the permission on that account from steam and adding the videos in steam from that account that has been created anonymously.

It will do the job for the time being.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "anonymous account" and how to do so?

Comment: anonymously mean creating an account without linkin it with google+  and idk,maybe not linking that with email, like mscrusifix. it will avoid verification by steam with so many account linked with that youtube account.it will do the job

Comment: I'm making a new question, this is still unanswered as your solution doesn't work

Comment: yes please../m\

Comment: why does a bounty cost 100 now and not 50?

Comment: oh.. gr8 man. actually i am also stucked here. but i researched a lot after this post on this on steam community but yea people are having trouble to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This problem was fixed by steam sometime yesterday and has no use to anyone anymore. I suggest closing.

Comment: yes. problem solved :)