# Steam cannot access my YouTube username

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I'm trying to link my YouTube account to Steam so I can share videos through it. However I'm getting this error:

[image: There was an error accessing YouTube to retrieve your username. Please try again.]

According to [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2811461) and [this](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/828939163742242781/), I need a YouTube *channel*, as well as having it linked to a Google+ account, and I definitely have both.

Has anyone else had this error? Is there any settings I might've missed?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/147215/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have a Google+ account on Youtube, you need to link your Youtube *page user* to Steam. A Steam Forums user [found the following solution](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/7/648814842665772098/):

> The issue is that Steam is trying to retrieve your Google+ account instead of your YouTube.
>
> 1. Make sure you have created a YouTube channel if you haven't already.
> 2. While on your YouTube channel (Make sure you are not on you Google+ account..this is important). Go to Setting and scroll down the page.
> 3. Stop where it says "Third party tools." There should be your YouTube email which looks something like this "xxxxxx-xxxxx@pages.plusgoogle.com"
> 4. Create a password.
> 5. Go to steam and link your account. When asked to log in. Use the email above and password that you created (Not your Google+ email). You should now have your account linked!!

This fixed the issue when I had it, and [here's Steam's support article about the issue,](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5316-TYOZ-0944) which should also give similar instructions to fixing it.